# TFS Prepare for Shutdown/Restart

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I am new to TFS.

Is there anyway to notify TFS to not to start new build/test/releases as we are about to restart/shutdown the TFS server?

Jenkins has a similar feature, where it puts up a banner saying 'Jenkins is going to shut down' and stop queuing new builds. Does TFS have such a feature?

Comment: You can disable the agents in the "Agent Pools" screen off the Settings menu. This will allow current running builds to complete, but prevent new builds being queued. There's nothing that will give an alerts to users, aside from them seeing their builds queue up.

Comment: Are you restarting your app tier so often that this is a concern? If so, why?

Comment: @DanielMann not often, but the TFS host machine is a Windows Server and it requests restart after updates. So I would want to restart the machine with proper notice to the whole team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing with an alert - there might be an extension, or you could build one to do the alerting, but the best you can do is disable the agent pools at the following address:

```
https://[my].visualstudio.com/_settings/agentpools
```

[image: Agent Pools]

This will stop the builds agents from queuing new builds in the pipeline until you re-enable them.

Answer (score 0):

On the application tier call `TFSServiceControl quesce`. The documentation for the command is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsservicecontrol-cmd